# button hide unhide in c# console application

Tags: c#

At the start of the application, a form must appear with two buttons on it. On the top button, the text “Button 1” must be written and on the bottom button the text “Button 2” must be written. The two buttons must be perfectly center aligned (both horizontally and vertically) in the client area of the form.
For the first time, when any of the button 1 or button 2 is clicked then it will disappear and the other button will stay unchanged. For example, user clicks button 1 for the first time then button 1 will disappear. Button 2 will be unchanged. Now there is only one button on the window that is button 2. On clicking button 2 it will disappear and button 1 will reappear on the window. Now if the user clicks button 1 then it will disappear again and button 2 will reappear. This process may go on indefinitely until the application is terminated by clicking the close button (on the top right corner of the window).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your problem? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you have buttons in console application ? I think you are meaning windows application ?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, SO is not here to do your homework for you...

Comment: If both buttons are "perfectly center aligned horizontally and vertically", then one will be on top of the other. They can both be perfectly aligned vertically OR horizontally, but in the other direction they should either be stacked or side by side.

Comment: You only need to add code in the click event of each button to hide itself and show the other button.

Answer (score 0):

Look

1- Inside the Event handler of each button just do:

2- change the visible property of the current button to false to hide it.

3- Check if the other button is hidden then make it visible again.

```
Button1.visible = !Button1.visible;
if (!Button2.visible) 
   {
     Button2.visible= true;  
   }
```

PS. that code as a logic and info not i didn't mean a specific programming language.

 is it what you search for?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking for.. but i interpret it as you need a code to make your button visible/not visible

```
button.visible=true;

button.visible=false;
```